# Map root JSON array to a property of type. .NET

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json, serialization

I have a JSON array with two objects. ex: [{},{}]

And I would like to map the root array to a property:

```
[JsonArray("Results")]
internal class CollectionResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public ItemsResponse[] Results { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot pass the collection to serializer while it's a custom assembly that receives BaseResponse type.

Probably there is an attribute to map root array to a child property?

Comment: What have you tried? With Newtonsoft JSON for example this should be super trivial.

Comment: Yes, I use Newtonsoft JSON. But i cannot find any attribute that will allow to do that! I have tried JsonArray but without any success...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple using Newtonsoft.Json library, because your property name for ItemsResponse array is the same as the Json model, you don't even need to use the attribute as the model binding is smart enough to use the variable name.

```
    private static void StackOverflow()
    {
        var jsonString = "{\"Results\":[{\"Item\":\"ItemName1\"},{\"Item\":\"ItemName2\"}]}";

        var collectionResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionResponse>(jsonString);
    }

    internal class CollectionResponse
    {
        public ItemsResponse[] Results { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ItemsResponse
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If you wish to have the array in json as root, then the above method is still sound, but you need to use the deserialization type as ItemResponse[].

```
    private static void StackOverflow()
    {
        var jsonString = "[{\"Item\":\"ItemName1\"},{\"Item\":\"ItemName2\"}]";

        var collectionResponse = new CollectionResponse()
        {
           Results =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemsResponse[]>(jsonString)
        };
    }

    [JsonArray]
    internal class CollectionResponse
    {
        public ItemsResponse[] Results { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ItemsResponse
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Not really an answer. While I have root json array that cannot be changed. Example: [{},{}]

Comment: No problems, I have edited the answer that should suit your scenario.

Comment: @Evgeny [{},{}] is not json! it should have a name/key

Comment: @DanielB I thought the same initially, but apparently validating [{},{}] against RFC 4627 - it is a valid json. [link]https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius  I know about the array option. But I use third party assembly and i cannot pass the collection there. The only option is to pass BaseResponse and that is mentioned in the question. I believe that only option is the custom deserializer.

Comment: @Evgeny Do you have an option to modify the json you are looking to deserialize? Adding { "Results" : + jsonString + } might be a suitable option to make the default deserialization to work